# Cannot assign to function call

Tags: javascript, function

I'm new in learning JavaScript. Just for some test I built this function and call it and assign a variable in it to a complete result. Is there a way use the function like this example?

Here I want to just pass `#country` in the `dom(i)` function. So it should be `getElementById("maid")`, and after calling it, assign `= maid` to put this *maid* variable after `innerHTML =`.

I'm wondering is it possible to write JavaScript function like this way?

```js
var maid = "Made In Yiappa";
function dom(i) {
    var docs = document.getElementById(i).innerHTML;
    return docs;
}
dom("country") = maid;
```

```html
<p> The result is: <span id="country"></span> </p>
```

Comment: What is the meaning of *"maid"*? Do you mean *"[made](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/make#Verb)"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass it as an argument to that function:

```js
var maid = "Made In Yiappa";
function dom(elementId, txt) {
    document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = txt;
}
dom("country", maid);
```

```html
<p> The result is: <span id="country"></span> </p>
```

Comment: That's great :-) Thank you.

Comment: Yes obviously. But I should wait 5 minute more to do this. new question restriction maybe

Comment: Why are you assigning the function to a new variable?

Comment: @Andy because the OP is trying to learn about Closures. I know that it sholud be done with a simple function.

Comment: Yes @Andy Im just earning and doing some horrible test :-) to find my mistakes

Comment: There's no mention of closures in the question, and you haven't provided an example in your answer.

Comment: @Andy ah, you're true. I modified my answer. It was so simple.

Comment: @stackBD21 there are still _no_ closures in your answer.

Comment: @Andy I can't understand what you mean by "no closures in your answer. I'm sorry but Can you please explain that again

Comment: You're not returning any "inner functions". All you're doing is assigning the function declaration to a new variable which seems a bit pointless. You should might want to consider removing that section about closures from your answer as it's very misleading.

Comment: @Andy now it's true?

Comment: No - sorry. I think you need to read the documentation you posted, and have a look at the examples on that page to get a better understanding of how closures work.

Comment: @Andy I haven't the time now... I removed that section

Answer (score 2):

1. The key issue is that you're returning the value of the `innerHTML` property from the function but you can't then assign a string to it because `innerHTML` can only be set when it's attached to an element.
2. [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) maybe a better method choice. You can then pass in your `#country` selector as you mentioned in your question.
3. So, we can remove some of the functionality from the function, and just have it return the element using the selector. Then we can assign `main` to the `innerHTML` of that returned element (although [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) might be more appropriate).

```js
var maid = 'Made In Yiappa';

function dom(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}

dom('#country').innerText = maid;
```

```html
<p> The result is: <span id="country"></span> </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can’t assign a value to the result of a function call. You need to pass it as a function argument.

```js
var maid = "Made In Yiappa";
function dom(i, text) {
    document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = text;
}
dom("country", maid);
```

```html
<p> The result is: <span id="country"></span> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not entirely sure that stackDB answers here is completely correct, but I am willing to be shown otherwise. The reasons being

1. No closure is created here as no function has been returned nor called by an event listener. I know all functions close over variables within the outer scope, but this could create confusion to the OP of the general use of a closure. I.e., a returned inner function using a local variable inside the function even after the outer function has finished execution.
2. You state the OP *must* assign the function to a variable. This too I believe is not accurate. A function declaration will do the job here, a function expression in this case is optional. Again this may create confusion to the OP’s understanding of hoisting and differences between function declarations and expressions.

Unfortunately I am not in a position to write code for the OP.

Comment: What is "stackDB"? The name of a user? If so, what answer does it refer to?